# Windows 2003 :: Performance Monitoring :: Simple/Stupid Tutorial

Tags: windows, iis-6, performance-monitoring, windows-server-2003

I have a half dozen front-end servers all running IIS 6.0-based/hosted applications. (primary .NET 2.0 web apps.) Basically, I'd like to take some basic performance data from each one, through such into a spreadsheet, and compare. CPU load, RAM load, whatever...

If anyone can point out a very simple/stupid "here's how you do that" type of tutorial, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TechNet Webcast: IIS 6.0 Performance and Tuning - Level 200](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032263485&EventCategory=3&culture=en-US&CountryCode=US)  and [TechNet Virtual Lab: IIS 6.0 Performance Tuning](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?EventID=1032286972&EventCategory=3&culture=en-US&CountryCode=US)

I think that's about as close to simple you are going to get for a relatively complex subject.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Performance Monitor (Perfmon) Counters for IIS - 2](http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Performance-Monitor-(Perfmon)-Counters-for-IIS-2.aspx) and [Performance Monitor (Perfmon) Counters for IIS - 3](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Performance-Monitor-(Perfmon)-Counters-for-IIS-3.aspx). It gives you enough information on how you setup Performance Monitor for the different counters and then use different tools to analyze the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pal](http://pal.codeplex.com/), it's not so much a tutorial on setting up perfmon, but more a tool for analysis of what comes out. It does offer guidance on what counters are most relevant for IIS, SQL, Exchange, etc.